# LongListSelector doesnt get updated from ViewModel when change occurs

Tags: windows-phone

My XAML file has the following:

```
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="lstSetups" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding BusRouteSetups}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSetup, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AccentForegroundBrush}" 
                            Foreground="{StaticResource AccentForegroundBrush}" 
                            Header="{Binding LabelsResources.AreaSetup, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource LocalizedLabels}}" 
                            Template="{StaticResource ListPickerControlTemplate}" 
                            ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" 
                            FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChooseAreaDataTemplate}" 
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AreaSetupNormalDataTemplate}"/>
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lBusRoutes" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSetupBusRoutes}"
                                SelectionChanged="lBusRoutes_SelectionChanged"
                                Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,12,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BusRoutesDataTemplate}"/>
```

Note that the ListPicker has a two way binding to SelectedSetup which is in the ViewModel. The LongListSelector has a binding to SelectedSetupBusRoutes in the View Model

The ViewModel has the following code:

```
    public Setup SelectedSetup
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedSetup;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedSetup != value)
            {
                _SelectedSetup = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSetup");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Route> SelectedSetupBusRoutes
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedSetup != null)
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<Route>(SelectedSetup.Routes);
            }
            return null; 
        }
    }
```

When i change the selected setup from the ListPicker that updates the ViewModel but it doesnt cause the LongListSelector to update. It does though updated if you move out the page and then go back in.

Should i handle the ListPicker change event and rebind the LongListSelector or is this something that could happen by the ViewModel but something is missing?

Comment: When chaning the `SelectedSetup` you want to update the `ObservableColelction` of Routes?

Comment: That is correct! I thought that since the SelectedSetupBusRoutes property is using the SelectedSetup property it would have updated itself when  NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSetup"); occurs. But it doesn't.

Comment: Call `NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSetupBusRoutes");` in your `SelectedSetup` Setter.

Comment: So it doesn't happen automatically based on the dependency?

Comment: No not in this case. You have to do it manually.